# rsync - on uncleaned shell and connection unexpectedly closed

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, shell

I want to run rync to a remote server which has an uncleaned shell. If someone tries to connect it via ssh shell, it'll show some warnings. Due to this issue I couldn't able to copy files.

```
protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(178) [sender=3.1.2]
```

## Question 1:

> Is there any way to run the rsync on an uncleaned shell?

Then I tried with a cleaned shell. I have removed all the warning messages and then verified with rsh command.

```
rsh -i key -p 2022 remotehost@user > output
```

There is no data and its size was 0.

Then I tried to do the sync, now im getting the below error.

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.2]
```

## Question 2:

> After cleanup, still getting error, what can be the reason?

#### rsync command

```
rsync -avz --progress -e "ssh -p 2022 -i mykey.pem" /tmp/test/ admin@10.10.10.1:/tmp/
```

Can anyone help me on this?

**I forgot to mention this earlier. I have enabled SSH session recording.**

Comment: You probably have something in the .bashrc that outputs something. Why are you testing with `rsh` and then using `ssh` for rsync?!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you first mention the command "rsh" and later the command is "ssh"?

This command is not supposed to produce an empty file, it should start an interactive shell and wait for input.

```
ssh -i key -p 2022 remotehost@user > output
```

It would seem your login shell immediately terminates, this is supported by the message `0 bytes received`. Did you place an "exit" somewhere while you removed the output from the shell?

Comment: I have enabled SSH session recording, I got to know that if session recording enabled, we can't use scp,rsync

Comment: What happens if you use the command `ssh -p 2022 -i mykey.pem admin@10.10.10.1 pwd`? Does it display the home directory of the user admin?